# How do you access gradle.ext properties in Plugin Java source code?

Tags: gradle, properties, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle.properties

I need a property to (one) be available when a plugin is applied and (two) allow for a calculated override value in the `settings.gradle` file. A project property would be ideal as it can have a default set in `gradle.properties`:

```
# gradle.properties
myProp=originalValue
```

This is great because it can be overrode with a command line argument like `-PmyProp=newValue`, but I was not able to find a good way to override the property in the `settings.gradle` file before the `build.gradle` executes (i.e. before the plugins are applied).

For instance all of these leave `rootProject.myProp` unaltered at plugin application:

```
// settings.gradle
rootProject.getProperties.put("myProp", "overrideValue")
settings.ext.myProp = "overrideValue"
settings.extensions.myProp = "overrideValue"
gradle.startParameters.projectProperties.myProp = "overrideValue"
```

We cannot do any magic in the `build.gradle` either because no logic can exist before the `plugins` block:

```
// build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.myCompany.myPlugin' version 1.0.0 // 'myProp' must be set by now
}
```

One workaround I can think of would be to use:

```
// settings.gradle
gradle.ext.myProp = "overrideValue"
```

... but there doesn't seem to be a good way to access `gradle.ext` properties in Java source code (for a plugin), or is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for the `gradle.ext.myProp` use case, but it is surprising to me that the only workable approach is to cast the Gradle object to an `ExtensionAware` object:

```
// MyPlugin.java
String myProp = (String) project.getRootProject().getProperties().getOrDefault("myProp", null);
Gradle gradle = project.getRootProject().getGradle();
if ((myProp == null)  && (gradle instanceof ExtensionAware)) {
    ExtensionAware gradleExtensions = (ExtensionAware) gradle;
    myProp = (String) gradleExtensions.getExtensions().getExtraProperties().get("myProp");
}
```

It seems like what I'm trying to do should be commonplace, so is there a better way like solely using project properties?

If so, then how do you change the values in the `settings.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you’re looking for but maybe it still helps: have you considered an [initialization script](https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.2/userguide/init_scripts.html)? In such a script it *is* possible to override a project property.

Example:

```
$ ./gradlew -PmyProp=originalValue properties | grep myProp
myProp: originalValue

$ ./gradlew -PmyProp=originalValue -I init.gradle properties | grep myProp
myProp: overrideValue
```

… where `init.gradle` is the following:

```
allprojects {
    project.ext.myProp = 'overrideValue'
}
```

Note that there are also [other ways of specifying](https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.2/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script) the init script.

Comment: This is a good point, but my main struggle is how do I change a project property using logic/code (which I believe must happen in the `settings.gradle` file), so it can be set/altered when a plugin is applied? _This needs to happen for all users that run the build._ It seems that the project properties cannot be manipulated in the `settings.gradle` file, so I had to use the Gradle properties.